# Memory usage in an Activity

Tags: android, image, performance

I know that managing images is something that we need to be very careful, mainly about using of memory.

In my case I am using the AVD manager to test my apps and in some cases I use my phone. The thing is when I test my app in a emulator the amount of memory used for a particular activity is around 25 MB. On the other side, when I test my app in my phone the amount of memory reaches 60 MB more or less.
It is good to know that both devices has the same resolution: 1080 X 1920.
The library to manage the images is Glide and the layout includes:

- a Carousel : https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview
- A recycleView with a StaggeredGridLayoutManager which has two columns

The question is: Is it normal this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be garbage collection.  Your emulator probably doesn't have as much memory as your device, so the garbage collection is more aggressive.  You can call System.gc() to try to force garbage collection at the same point in your code, then the memory could be the same.  No need to leave that in there though.

Answer (score 0):

You can limite the cache size for your images , to do it you use `LruCache`

First you go get the `MaxMemory` after that you set a `cacheSize` and after that you make a simple initialisation of your `LruCache`.

 Hope that helped you.